# How to post a form with Image and other kinds of input in Vue to API Laravel?

Tags: laravel, forms, image, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a form with some fields about the Product (name, brand, ..., image), I want to send all the data to my API and then create and save in my database, the image that must be saved in a folder.

The problem is that I am sending the data (dataProduto) via $ post and in my API the $ request is not receiving the data.

**Before** having an image on this form it worked fine, but I changed it to formData.append ('dataProduct', this.dataProduct) and sent it and then it stopped working. **Now** my backend looks like it's not getting the data, it's like dataProduct [object, object];

Here it's the frontend:

```js
< script >
  import axios from 'axios';
import {
  VueEditor
} from 'vue2-editor';

const url = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL;

export default {
  name: 'TableProducts',
  components: {
    Loader,
    VueEditor,
    Tabs,
    Tab,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      dadosProduto: {},
      valid: false,
      previewImage: null,
      url_image: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async save() {
      if (this.dadosProduto) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('dadosProduto', this.dadosProduto);
        try {
          const {
            data: returnInsert
          } = await axios.post(`${url}products/create`, formData);
          if (returnInsert.status === 200) {
            this.$root.$emit('evento-msg', {
              tipoMsg: 'sucesso',
              titulo: 'Inclusão de Produto',
              msg: returnInsert.data.message,
            });
          }
          if (returnInsert.status === 500) {
            this.$root.$emit('evento-msg', {
              tipoMsg: 'erros',
              titulo: 'Inclusão de Produto',
              msg: returnInsert.data.message,
            });
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
<div class="containerList">
  <div class="headerList">
    <h1>Incluir Produto</h1>
    <div class="optionList">
      <div class="btnList">
        <button type="button"
        class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark me-md-2"
        @click="home()">Voltar
        </button>
        <button type="button"
        class="btn btn-sm btn btn-primary me-md-2"
        @click.prevent="save">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <v-form
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      ref="form"
      v-model="valid"
      lazy-validation>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col
          cols="12"
          sm="6"
          md="4">
            <v-text-field
              v-model.number="dadosProduto.codigo"
              label="Código">
            </v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col
          cols="12"
          sm="6"
          md="4">
            <vue-editor class="editorEcommerce"
                  v-model="dadosProduto.descricao"
                  label="Descrição">
            </vue-editor>
          </v-col>
          <v-col
          cols="12"
          sm="6"
          md="4"
          class="columnImage">
          <v-file-input
            v-model="dadosProduto.imagem_principal"
            @change="Preview_image"
            accept="image/*"
            label="File input"
          ></v-file-input>
          <v-img
            class="imagem"
            :src="url_image"
            upload-behavior="delayed"></v-img>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
</div>
</template>
```

Here it's the backend:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $produto = $request->all();

        if (empty($produto['gtin'])) {
            throw new Exception('Para incluir é necessário informar o GTIN do produto.');
        } 

        try {   
            if( $this->produtoFacades->salvarProdutoCreate($produto) ) {
                return response()->json([
                    'data'   => ['message' => 'Produto criado com sucesso.'],
                    'status' => 200,
                ]);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        } catch (ClientException $e) {
            return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'data'   => ['message' => $e->getMessage()],
            'status' => 500,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check if you hit the create function successfully? Your API route looks strange. Why didn't you have "api"  prefix in your route?

Comment: Yes, it hits the create function, I had some Console.log in the function create and it show me the variable $produto it's like [object,object].
What you mean about having "api" prefix in my route?

Comment: Do you have console.log in PHP, how? Laravel api routes are like this "/api/product".

Comment: Yes, I console.log here...   
               $produto = $request->all();
                echo '<script>';
                echo 'console.log('. json_encode($produto) .')';
                echo '</script>';

Comment: I don't know if it will solve your problem but I suggest you pass this.dadosProduto directly instead of form data. I always pass a plain object with Axios, and it works.

Comment: Yes, I had it before and it worked perfectly fine, but then my image will be post? on my console.log it looks like null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve  the issue I had to pass a formData, and use the property name="" in all my inputs.

before send the request by Axios I added the following code:

```
 const form = document.getElementById('form');
 const formdata = new FormData(form);
```